# Select specific field and get result from array in jsonb field

Tags: json, postgresql

If I put this data to `jsonb` field:

```
{'name': 'pratha', 'email': 'p@g.com', 'sub': { 'id': 1 } }
```

I was able to select `name` with this query:

```
SELECT data_field->>'name' from users where ....
```

However, When they are in `array`, this query doesn't work:

```
[
   {'name': 'pratha', 'email': 'p@g.com', 'sub': { 'id': 1 } },
   {'name': 'john', 'email': 'c@d.com', 'sub': { 'id': 2 } }
]
```

How can I select each `name` in array?

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/22166

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a lateral cross join of `jsonb_array_elements()` to get the array's elements. Then you can extract the name from each element.

```
SELECT sr.*,
       jae.e->>'name'
       FROM survey_results sr
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(sr.data_field) jae (e);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/22166/6)